# In how many bases the last digit of $2013$ will remain $3$?

Tags: number-theory

In $10$ base number system, the last digit of $(2013)$ is $3$
But When it is written in base $9$ then $(2676)_9$, So, the last digit is 6

Then, in how many bases the last digit of $2013$ will remain $3$?

Comment: how do you want digits represented in bases above 10?

Comment: @costrom Yes, the base can go above 10.

Comment: @costrom That doesn't matter. The question boils down to: for what $n$ is $2013= 3 \pmod n$.

Comment: @RezwanArefin If you still don't see this think about this: if $2013-3=2010$ is divisible by some number $n$ ($n >3$) this means that $2010$ can be written in some base $n$ without remainder , or ,in other words,the last digit in that base is $0$ so when you add $3$ you can substitute it as last digit ($2010= ab...c3_n$ where the subscript $n$ indicates the base in which the number is written).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last digit always represents the digit for $b^0=1$. You can generally say that it will be the represented number modulo the base. So you're asking for how many numbers $n$ does $2013\equiv3\mod n$ hold. For $n>3$ this is equivalent to asking for the factors of $2010$. Factorizing $2010$ can be easily done by hand and will yield the answer to your question. Also, we need to subtract $3$ from the number of factors of $2010$ since the factors $1,2,3$ will not leave $3$ as the remainder.